# When should I quit my job?

Tags: job-change

I am a entry level customer support engineer. Looks like this is not a very technical job. The contract is of 2 years. If I leave early, I'd have to pay 3 months equivalent of salary. My degree is in computer engineering. IDK why I am doing this job. I wanted to spend some time learning various subjects like programming, software testing, linux, and get a job in devops or testing.

I also want to enter government service in computer engineering.

Currently, I have to do little bit of work in linux and sql in this job. I am based in Nepal.

When should I leave my job? My parents forced me to take up this job as I was unemployed for a long period(1 year).

Comment: Nobody here can answer this for you.

Comment: You should maybe have a local employment lawyer look at your contract. That seems awfully harsh and it's not entirely clear whether this is legal.

Comment: @Hilmar I thought this was the norm. This is in one of the top IT companies of Nepal. Probably the #1 Nepali company.

Comment: @zeeshanseikh It’s unlikely that anyone here knows the rules for Nepal. Elsewhere the rules are usually: you get paid for the time you work and not paid for the time you don’t work. I contract says how much notice you or the company have to give (for example a contract can say you have to tell the company one month before you leave) and there can be penalties if you don’t. But if you give enough notice you wouldn’t pay anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should quit your job, when you have a new job lined up, that is better than your current job and where you have a written contract signed by both parties.

Alternatively, you should quit your job as soon as you can, if it actively causes you harm.

Assuming your job is just "boring" and not harming you in any way, the answer is to find a new job, that pays so well, that you can afford the losses stipulated in your old contract. If none comes along until you are free to leave without additional fees, find a job that is simply better than your current job. If you can't find one, keep trying while you stay and earn a living in your old job.

Comment: that's never going to happen without quitting current job.